# ns-2 - ./validate fails in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: validation, ns2, ubuntu-13.10

I was able to make ns-2 (ns-allinone-2.35) install on Ubuntu 13.10 successfully by modifying linkstate/ls.h, but one test case in the validation suite always seems to fail - tcpLinux. This bothers me because validation works properly in Ubuntu 12. Would you know how to fix this or if this is an issue at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: NS2 is deprecated. They stopped working on it some years ago. That must be the reason why they aren't updating the codebase.

Comment: Also, did you install NS2 with `apt-get install ns2`? Ubuntu has [NS2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/ns2) in its repository.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I'm aware that NS2 is deprecated but one of my classes still requires it, unfortunately, because the protocol support of NS3 is still less than NS2. Right now I'm trying to build it with an older version of gcc (4.4). If that doesn't work, will try out the apt-get method.

Btw, I've heard people say that it's not important to have every test case pass in the validation. Is this true? Sorry, I'm just starting to learn NS2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like ns-2 doesn't play nice with the newer versions of gcc.

Before installing, do

```
export CC=gcc-4.4 CXX=g++-4.4
```

If you don't have these older versions, use

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4 g++-4.4
```

Using this method, I didn't have to modify any source code before building.